# How to make bootstrap table work on blazor webassembly

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I installed the css and js libraries according to the instructions to the index.html file, then I created the table on the .razor file but bootstrap table doesn't work in blazor. Please help me, thank you very much.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.19.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.19.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
    
    
    <table data-toggle="table" data-search="true" data-show-columns="true">
    ...
  </table>
```

Comment: Demo: https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#welcomes/from-html.html

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.